# Jenkinsfile stage failing when I use msbuild15 to build an c# app

Tags: c#, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use **msbuild** in my jenkinsfile stage and I have couple of errors:

- *Unable to find the "BouncyCastle.Crypto" assembly*
- *SecurityCertificateUtil.cs(1,7): error CS0246: Type or namespace name 'randomName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assemblyÿ reference?)*

**My jenkinsfile look like :**

```
stage('Build Artifact with C#') {
    agent { node { label 'name' } }
    steps {                  
        bat """
        cd app/
        \"${tool 'MSBuildTools15'}\" RandomName.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\"
        """           
    }
}
```

I managed to build the solution locally in the builder by using Visual Code 2017 but via jenkins pipeline doesn't work properly